# JMock causes JUnit ExpectedException to pass even if an exception is not thrown

Tags: java, junit, jmock

When I use JMock with JUnit `ExpectedException` the tests seem to pass even if the exception is not thrown. For example, the test below fails, as it should. But if I uncomment the two commented lines, it passes. Am I doing something wrong? Is there an incompatibility between these two components?

```
//@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class JUnitJMockTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    //Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery();

    @Test
    public void test() {

        exception.expect(NullPointerException.class);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may find [this page](http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2012/03/27/expecting-exception-with-junit-rule/) useful. Quoting from it:

> Beware though that if you combine the rule with certain `@RunWith` classes, you may get a false positive. Specifically, if you were to run with a class that extends `JUnit4ClassRunner` in the above example, the test would no longer fail. You’d get a false positive.
>
> For example, if you’re using a version of JMock prior to `2.6.0` and use `@RunWith(JMock.class)` you’ll encounter this. Older versions of the `JMock.class` extend `JUnit4ClassRunner` and `JUnit4ClassRunner` ignores rules. The newer `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` supports rules and JMock post 2.6.0 extend this in `JMock.class`.

In short, it sounds like you may be using a version of JMock prior to 2.6.0 and an update may solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I was using jMock 2.5.0. Thanks very much for your help.